# GraphQL rate limit on mutations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am trying to implement a rate limit on GraphQL **Mutation** when creating new users. I successfully implemented it in Queries but could not do the same on Mutations, any advice or resource on how I can solve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

- imports in resolvers/users

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { UserInputError } = require('apollo-server');
const { getGraphQLRateLimiter } = require('graphql-rate-limit')

const { validateCreateInput } = require('../../util/validators');
const User = require('../../models/User');
```

- rate limiter declaration

```
const rateLimiter = getGraphQLRateLimiter({ identifyContext: (ctx) => ctx.id });
```

- Query with rate limitation which works fine

```
Query: {
        getUsers: async (parent, args, context, info) => {
            try {
                const errorMessage = await rateLimiter(
                    { parent, args, context, info },
                    { max: 1, window: '3s' }
                );
                if (errorMessage) throw new Error(errorMessage);
                const users = await User.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 });
                return users;
            } catch (err) {
                throw new Error(err);
            }
        },
    },
```

- My problem occurs here on **Mutation** when trying to create user with rate limit

```
Mutation: {
        async createUser(_, {
            createInput: {
                name,
                email,
                role,
                password,
                confirmPassword
            }
        }) {

            /****** problem here ******/
            
            const errorMessage = await rateLimiter(
                { parent, args, context, info },
                { max: 1, window: '3s' }
            );
            if (errorMessage) throw new Error(errorMessage);

            /****** problem here ******/

            const { valid, errors } = validateCreateInput(name, email, role, password, confirmPassword);

            if (!valid) {
                throw new UserInputError('Errors', { errors })
            }

            const duplicateEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

            if (duplicateEmail) {
                throw new UserInputError('Email is already used', {
                    errors: {
                        email: 'Email is already used'
                    }
                })
            }

            password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);

            const newUser = new User({
                name,
                email,
                role,
                password,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
            })

            const res = await newUser.save();

            return {
                ...res._doc,
                id: res._id
            }
        }
    }
```

- The error that I am getting while creating new user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear, check the difference between your query resolver and your mutation resolver. You need something like:

```js
Mutation: {
  async createUser(parent, args, context, info) { ... }
}
```

Then parent and other required fields will be defined.

Comment: This will not give me access to createInput fields, and printing this error  `"message": "Cannot read property 'createInput' of undefined"`